# DAO access recordset not updating

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao, recordset

I have an access report that updates 4 image controls based on a table that is sourcing images from a directory.  The report generates a page per record, however the image controls are not changing after page 1 (just showing same images for all the other pages).  Appartently, the code worked fine on Windows XP and now does not work on Windows 7 OS (both used Office 07).  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Report_Current()

    UpdateImages
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Load()

    UpdateImages
End Sub
Private Sub Report_Page()

    UpdateImages
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateImages()
On Error GoTo errHandler
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset

    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Image_Loc, Image_Name FROM HH_Media WHERE InspectionID = " & CInt(Me.InspectionID.Value) & " ORDER BY MediaID ASC")

    If Not RS.BOF And Not RS.EOF Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To 4
            If Not RS.EOF Then
                Dim pictureCtrl As Image
                Set pictureCtrl = GetControl("Image" & i)

                Dim strImage As String
                strImage = RS.Fields("Image_Loc").Value & "\" & RS.Fields("Image_Name").Value


               If Not pictureCtrl Is Nothing Then
                    If FileExists(strImage) Then
                        pictureCtrl.Picture = strImage
                        SetLabel "lblImage" & i, RS.Fields("Image_Name").Value
                    Else
                        pictureCtrl.Picture = ""
                        SetLabel "lblImage" & i, "Does not exist"
                    End If
               End If

              RS.MoveNext

            Else
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

    End If

    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing

Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred while updating the form display." & vbNewLine & Err.Description, vbApplicationModal + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton1 + vbOKOnly, Me.Name
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

The images do exist in the directory that are referenced in the table.  Any ideas of what is missing?

Thank You

Comment: I don't know, but it seems like Microsoft randomly removes various API features in new releases.  When I updated from Access 2000 to 2007, a bunch of features were broken because FileDialog and RecordSet.RecordCount no longer existed.

Comment: Are you sure the UpdateImages is being called after page 1 - sometimes the page event doesn't fire...

Comment: @DJ., It seems like it is only hitting the UpdateImage procedure 4 times.  How do I make the event fire per page?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I need to do some dynamic content I always use the [section]_Format event - so if your controls are on the Detail section then:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

  If FormatCount = 1 then  'only need to do this once per record
    UpdateImages
  Endif

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the GetControl method, and I don't have a lot of experience using the Image control, but it seems like that the Dim statement should read more like:

```
Dim pictureCtrl as Control
Set pictureCtrl = Me.Controls("Image" & i)
```

I would insert a break and verify that

```
strImage = RS.Fields("Image_Loc").Value & "\" & RS.Fields("Image_Name").Value
```

is returning values you expect.  You can also shorten these to:

```
strImage = rs!Image_Loc & "\" & rs!Image_Name
```

sometimes Access doesn't like the added ".value" as this is already the default return.